# 2D vector allocator trouble

Tags: c++, stdvector, allocator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> test1(1);

    test1[100] = 5.;

    std::vector< std::vector <double > > test2(1, std::vector<double>(1,0));

    test2[50][100] = 5.;
}
```

`test1` : resizes and allocates memory nicely

`test2` :`"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`. Why?

**Note**: Cannot use matrix, since row size are unequal.

**Summary**:
`at(int)`: checks bounds and throws exception if necessary - no resizing

`operator[](int)` :doesnot check bounds - no resizing

`push_back()` : resizes increases `capacity()` by double if current capacity is small

`size()` : number of elements in `vector`

`capacity()` : maximum elements to hold before a re allocation is necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access element with index 100 of a vector of size 1. You should not access index out of a vector bounds. Truth is that it is pure luck that it works in the first case instead of strange that second does not work.

A vector expands on call to `resize()` or `push_back`, but simply accessing an index does not expand the vector's size. Instead it causes an undefined behavior.

To fix the code do(change the sizes used when constructing the vectors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> test1(101);

    test1[100] = 5.;

    std::vector< std::vector <double > > test2(51, std::vector<double>(101,0));

    test2[50][100] = 5.;
}
```

Comment: don't vectors auto-resize?

Comment: @aiao Only when you push items into it whith e.g. `push_back`. And then only by one.

Comment: sorry about that. Got confused between `operator[]` and `at` and resizing.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing outside of the boinds of each vector:

```
std::vector<double> test1(1); // size 1 vector
test1[100] = 5.; // out of bounds access
```

The result is undefined behaviour. If you want to make a size 100 vector, do this:

```
std::vector<double> test1(101); // size 101 vector
test1[100] = 5.; // OK, access 101th element
test.push_back(42); // push element, size is now 102
```

Comment: @aiao they do if you `push_back` into them.

Comment: You're actually still access out of bounds on the size 100 vector, since you access element 101. :)

Comment: if you allocate a vector of size 100, you can't access `test1[100]`, as that is the 101st entry. A vector with 100 entries has entries 0-99.

Answer (score 1):

> test1 : resizes and allocates memory nicely

std::vector will resizes and allocates memory when call [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), but not random through random access operator

> test2 :"Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Why?

Below code accesses out of boundary of test1, test2:

```
test1[100] = 5.0;
test2[50][100] = 5.0;
```

You could test vector size to before access

```
if (test1.size() > 100))
{
    test1[100] = 5.0;
}
```

Or could use [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function with try/catch block:

```
try
{
    test2.at(50).at(100) = 5.0;
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
   std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want operator[] to automatically expand/insert, use a std::map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<double> test1;

    test1[100] = 5.; // Will insert one element into test1

    std::map< std::map <double > > test2;

    test2[50][100] = 5.; // will create a new map<double> and insert one element into it.
}
```

Comment: `map<int, double>` and `std::map<int, std::map <int, double > >`?